# Balls in Boxes Probability using method other than Binomial distribution

Tags: probability

> Twelve balls are distributed at random among three boxes. What is the probability that the first box will contain 3 balls ?

I tried solving it the following way
$$\frac{\dbinom{9}{2}}{\dbinom{12}{3}}$$The logic behind this is that if 3 balls are placed in the first box, then the we need bother only about the rest of the 9 balls being placed in the 2 remaining boxes. The answer given the text uses binomial probability distribution, I understood that intrepretation. But can somebody tell me how my answer is wrong ?.

Comment: Your answer looks closer to using hypergeometric than using binomial. The binomial distribution looks like $\binom nr p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$, not as a fraction with one binomial coefficient in the numerator and one in the denominator. Incidentally, I think this binomial formula is the correct formula to use, for appropriate $n, r, p$.

Comment: Yes I understood the binomial and its use in the problem. But my method seems right as well, but it does not lead to the correct answer. Where do you think my logic is faltering ?

Comment: I think your formula assumes that 3 fixed balls are in the first box...because you assume that 3 (specific) balls are in the first box and calculate the possibilities for the other balls..

Comment: Thank you RoyPJ I see where I'm wrong.

Comment: In fact your statement after "the logic behind this" is completely correct--once you know which 3 balls of the original 12 are in the first box, the other 9 have to go in the other 2 boxes--but the formula above that line has no reasonable basis in that statement. It's like you just took the four numbers from the statement and shoved them into an unrelated formula. Don't do math that way.

Comment: The reason why the formula is unrelated is because I had assumed that specific balls were kept in box 1. But since the balls aren't numbered the formula becomes wrong ?... Is that right David K

Comment: the "distributing at random" process implies that I can choose 3 boxes where to put the first ball, 3 for the 2nd, ..., $3^{12}$ in total: that is the corresponding space of *equi-probable* events.

Comment: That clears it up!. Thanks a lot G Cab.

Comment: Glad to help: That's a very insidious trap in the "balls-bins" scheme !